# python selenium says xpath expression is not valid

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I was trying to exercise with selenium and I tried this:

```
phone = driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//table[@class='contact_info_table']/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(), r'\+[0-9]*']"))
```

in order to try to get the phone number that it's inside a table. The HTML of the table is the following:

```
<table class="contact_info_table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>......</th>
        <td>
            . . .
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>......</th>
        <td>
            . . .
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Telefono:</th>
        <td><img style="vertical-align:middle; display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px;" src="../img/flags/it.png" title="Italia">+1234567890</td>
    </tr>
```

What I need to do is to get the 1234567 in the last tr. What am I doing wrong?

The error that I get is:

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "//table[@class='contact_info_table']/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(), r'\+[0-9]*']]" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried with `//table[@class='contact_info_table']/tbody/tr[th[.='Telefono:']]/td` xpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you missed a parenthesis in part of your path -- after your regex, you have two closing `]]`, but you need a `)` to replace the 2nd to last `]` in order to close up the `contains` query:

```
//table[@class='contact_info_table']/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(), r'\+[0-9]*')]
```

I'm also not sure if the regex you are using is valid syntax for XPath. I think you need to use the `matches()` method in the XPath -- like this:

```
/td[matches(text(), '\+[0-9]*']]
```

I replaced your `contains` with `matches`, and removed the preceding `r` from your regex because I think your expression just needs to be `'\+[0-9]*'`. Hopefully this helps a bit.

You also might not need to use regex at all to find the element you are trying to locate. Here's an alternate XPath that doesn't use regex, but still locates the element by grabbing the desired `td` element as a sibling of the preceding `th`:

```
//th[text()='Telefono:']//following-sibling::td
```

So, to get the phone number, you can use `.text`:

```
phone = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//th[text()='Telefono:']//following-sibling::td").text
```

Comment: Thank you very much! @Christine

Now it doesn't give me the error anymore, but I don't know why, when I try to print the value of phone it doesn't print nothing. The same goes for another variable which is the name and ins contained in a span inside a div. 

This is the code:
`name = driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//div[@class='head info']/span")).text
print('Name: ')
print(name)
phone = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//th[text()='Telefono:']//following-sibling::td").text
print("Phone: ")
print (phone)`

The output is: 

`Name:

Phone:

`

Comment: That code looks correct — if you XPath was wrong, you would encounter NoSuchElementException, so it seems like web element is being found.  Can you remove `.text` from both elements (so you are just printing the actual web element reference) to verify something is actually being located? That is first step to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thaink you again for your support. I've done that and it seems like it has found the elements, so I can't get why it doesn't print the text. This is the output:

`Name: 
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="dd7d88e8-ca54-45fd-af25-dea9bc7c59c9", element="2c263f3f-d320-4ac0-ac03-b81663950eaa")>
Phone: 
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="dd7d88e8-ca54-45fd-af25-dea9bc7c59c9", element="5a7c3f4d-64c5-41f4-a42c-a5e23a62b1de")>`

Comment: Yes, those are indeed valid web elements printing out. My best guess is that the wrong element is being located somehow — perhaps the XPath query is actually locating multiple elements, and the first one getting returned and printing out is not correct one. You can try to use `//table[@class='contact_info_table']/tbody/tr/th[text()='Telefono:']/following-sibling::td` (more specific than path in my post) and see if that helps. We might need to see the full page source to figure out what’s really going on here.

Comment: Changing `find_element_by_xpath` to `find_elements_by_xpath` and then `print(len(phone))` will help tell us if the XPath is locating multiple elements.

Comment: Tried with the more specific path but didn't work as well. Tried the second and in shows that the len is just one. So I can't really get what is happening here

Comment: That's incredibly strange -- only one element is being located, but it's somehow not the right one. My last suggestion would be `//table[@class='contact_info_table']/tbody/tr[th[contains(text(),'Telefono:')]]/td` which just uses a different query syntax than earlier suggestions. Apologies this has been so difficult to work out, sometimes automation is just trial and error.

Comment: Nope.. This doesn't work too. The strange thing is that I can't even get the span inside the div class where the name is contained. That's the code of this div (maybe it can help :/)

`<div class="head info">
    <span>YOUR NAME HERE</span>

    <div class="clear"></div>

</div>`

I am the one who should apologize for boring you with this. I am really thankful  for all the support you are giving to me!

Comment: Is there any way you could post the full page source or a link to the page you are automating? This would allow me to try and debug what's going on here. Personal info can be removed, I just want to render a version of the page to see if we can test against it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the full page source or a link of the page. If you want I can try to ask if I can share the source of the outer bloc where all the information I need are located.

Comment: Yes, even that might help a bit. Based on the current page source details provided, everything you are trying here should be working correctly, so I am trying to figure out if there is anything else happening in the DOM that might be causing these issues.

Comment: Ok I maged to do that. I can send you the outer div. Can I paste it here or should I paste it somewhere else in order not to mess up?

Comment: Adding the HTML to your original question would be best.

Comment: Done, whenever you want you can look at it. Really thank you so much!

Comment: I've fixed the problem! The problem was that the first time that one will open the link a page, a page with a button named enter that allows to actually enter the page I was trying to access. Thank you so much however for your help!

Comment: Glad you found the root cause here, hope the solution has helped you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xpath that you can use.

```
//table[@class='contact_info_table']/tbody/tr[th[.='Telefono:']]/td
```

[image]